# JGit！Can i get commitMessage without clone repository?

Tags: java, jgit

I want to get commit message and commit author through JGit without clone it.

I found the way `Git.lsRemoteRepository()` can access **remote repository**, but it just can get the commitId but not other info.
　　And i also know just clone the repository's ".git" file through JGit can get commit message and commit author,but there are too many repositories,it's impossible to clone each repository.
　　**So is there any ways to achieve that through JGit or other java package?**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know only the commit-ids are available without cloning due to the way the Git remote protocol is defined.

For repositories hosted on GitHub you can use other Java clients, e.g. https://github-api.kohsuke.org/ did work for me.

Comment: OK，i will find other ways do it.Thanks anyway!!